# Http_referrer shows Facebook but I wasn't on facebook

Tags: facebook, coldfusion

This is the weirdest thing. I have very simple CF code that looks at cgi.HTTP_REFERER. Simply, it looks at referrer. It the link was clicked from outside our main website domain, it displays something. Otherwise, nothing happens. So, if someone clicks a link from FB and it goes to our website, it displays something. If someone clicked the link from our homepage on our website, it does nothing.

There is a specific link that when clicked from our homepage, the "does something" happens. I wrote out all the variables and the http_referrer shows https://m.facebook.com. I wasn't on Facebook when I clicked the link. I wasn't on mobile. I was on my main website homepage when I clicked the link.

Now, here's the only things I can imagine:

1. We have facebook commenting on that story page.
2. that URL has been shared on Facebook.

But, we share all of our stories on Facebook and they all have FB commenting so I would think if FB stored this information, I would be having this issue on all pages.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You directly clicked on link on your website and you have a refer as facebook. Is that what you are telling?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was on my own website. Clicked a link to another page on my website and it said I came from m.facebook.com

Comment: How are you checking it ? Try checking it in browser. Tamper Data plugin may be.

Comment: When I check it with http_referrer, it shows facebook. When I use PAGE INFO in FF for example, it shows correctly. I have tested in multiple browsers, multiple computers and MAC vs PC. Same results.

Comment: Can you show us the html code for the link in question?

Comment: Visit www.lex18.com. Find the story about the Baseball Player injured. May be on page 2. Click the story and you'll see an ad overlay the page. That should NOT happen. Close that window. Scroll to the bottom of the page and you see where I output the http elements and look for http_referrer.

Comment: Ok, so now as I go back and refresh the link, it's not working as it was for 4+ hours this morning. But I have no doubt if I click around and more stories over the upcoming days, I'll see the same thing. I just dont understand why it would say m.facebook

Comment: Ok, and now I see it showing FB again....

Comment: When I went to that article the first time I got the facebook referer but also an incorrect user agent. It reported mine as an iPad `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B329 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/5.6;FBBV/144493;FBDV/iPad3,1;FBMD/iPad;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/6.1.3;FBSS/2; FBCR/;FBID/tablet;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/0]`. After refreshing the page it correctly showed my user agent as Windows 7 `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31` still facebook and also the wrong IP `108.161.254.245`

Comment: I tried it is Chrome and FireFox and it worked as expected - the correct http_referrer was shown.

Comment: Another refresh resulted in different results; referer `http://www.wlextv.com/home/`, user agent `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3)`, IP `128.163.7.150`.  None of which are me.

Comment: How/where are you dumping the CGI scope?  It almost seems like it is just dumping the values of the last user or something.  If you just sit on that article page and refresh your browser you will get different values.

Comment: When that page loads, I am calling in an file that reads and displays the information.

Comment: Can you show us that code?

Comment: Whatever you are dumping is definately not accurate.  Is your site using a proxy or a load balancer infront of your server?  For example, the IP address its returning for me is off. 2) your server name should be www.lex18.com and its returning www1.lex18.com or maybe your in an iframe from another site?

Comment: I'm going to investigate this a little more. Back soon.

Answer (score 1):

As with others, my user_agent, remote_addr and an referer are all incorrect. I also see different remote_addr values depending on which browser I use. So whatever you are dumping, it is not the CGI scope for *my* request.

I suspect you have a function which handles the dumping of the CGI scope, it's in a CFC that's in a persistent scope and you have an unVARed variable in there somewhere? Or your page-caching (possibly on a front-side proxy?) based on browser, and the dump in the cache?

NB: on *Opera* and *Safari* I do not get Facebook as the referer.